# Annotating data points with comma seperators

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to annotate the data points on my chart and return the annotations with comma separators between each 3 digits e.g ($20,000,000).

This is the code I have the annotations so far

```
for i in ax_fore.patches:
    # get_x pulls left or right; get_height pushes up or down
    ax_fore.text(i.get_x(), i.get_height(), \
            f'R {round(i.get_height(),2)}', fontsize=40, color='black',rotation=55)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the last line for:

```
 f'R {round(i.get_height(),2):,}', fontsize=40, color='black',rotation=55)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [string format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method supports thousands separators:

```
print('${:,}'.format(20000000))
# $20,000,000
```